How to concatenate a number and an incremental number that resets on year change?
I have this Access 365 table called Facturació:
enter image description here
The image shows the result i'd like to achieve, that is, the column Nº Factura (Invoice number) is a concatenation of the year taken from the DataFactura field (year(DataFactura)) and an incremental number that resets to 1 when year(DataFactura) changes. How can I achieve this?
Thanks for your help!

Generating a custom unique identifier is a common topic. Do research and when you have code with issue, post it in question.

The question here may be a better duplicate for this question.

This seems like a very bad design for creating a unique identifier. You are going to run into all kinds of locking issues especially if multiple invoices are entered at the same time (or you started one and wait for information and enter another one while you wait).
